# Is there a JavaScript MVC (micro-)framework?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, forms

Are there any client-side JavaScript [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (micro-)frameworks?

I have a rather complicated HTML form, and it would benefit from the MVC pattern.

I imagine a good solution would provide the following:

- Model and View update the Controller when values change (Observer pattern)
- Populate the model from the form data when the page loads
- Populate the form from the model when the model changes

Ajax, comet, [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and all that jazz are serious overkill.

Comment: Am I wrong or is this just a bad idea (or perhaps a framework being buzzword-compliant)?.

Comment: I started working on something a little while ago because I had the same feeling as you. It's as minimal as it gets, AMD and as unopinionated as I could get it. That means no jQuery etc. I know this has been closed now, but I think this *might* be the kind of thing you were looking for: https://github.com/Wolfy87/tarmac - I haven't done much with it recently because I thought I would be the only user.

Comment: https://github.com/yuval-a/ZOE

Comment: Have a look at [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/), which compares (nearly) all available JavaScript frameworks by implementing a simple TODO App.

Comment: Look at stimulusjs - for an existing app with server side generated markup, i found this framework to be minimal, least invasive and to the point. Really fun to work with. But may not satify all your requirements

Answer (score 70):

Backbone is a great light-weight framework. Give it a try:
http://backbonejs.org/

Comment: I am SO glad I found Backbone.

Comment: I agree, one to check out definitely!

Comment: How to use Backbone in MVC way?

Comment: @TristanJuricek is there a free alternative to peepcode?

Comment: Skip Backbone and go right for Spine.  It's got a much more logical MVC implementation.

Answer (score 33):

[JavaScriptMVC](http://www.javascriptmvc.com/) is an excellent solution.  It's everything is a plugin approach enables you to select only the features you need.  As of 2.0, it's based on jQuery.

On progressively enhancing your website, that's left up to the user as JMVC provides just a middle layer for development - it's up to you to make that design choice yourself.

However, JavaScriptMVC is simply the best general purpose JavaScriptMVC library because of its powerful event delegation based controllers.

Event delegation lets you escape having to attach event handlers, and simply create rules for your page.

Finally, JMVC is much more than a MVC architecture.  It has all parts of the development cycle covered with:

- Code Generators
- Selenium and Env.js integrated testing
- Documentation Engine
- Automatic Concat+Compress
- Error detection and reporting

Comment: +1 for JavascriptMVC - I've used it for a few apps now, and it's pretty nice.  Skip the code generation examples on the website.  I'd imagine those are only there to pacify the Rails fanboys.  :)  Start with the basic JQueryMX object model, and create a controller.

Comment: Since I made this comment, I've switched to using Require and Spine.  Ultimately they are smaller, more elegant, and less 'Enterprisey' than JMVC.  JMVC was nice for our team of Java developers to make the adjustment to JS, but it just doesn't hold up once you start to understand JS better...

Comment: The MVC part of JMVC is now [can.js](http://canjs.com/)

Answer (score 21):

[Spine](https://github.com/spine) has an API similar to Backbone but it's a lot smaller. It features prototypal inheritance.

Comment: It's also written in CoffeeScript and uses CoffeeScript's style of classes — not that that's a huge win, but it's kinda nice.

Comment: I assume that's why it's small than backbone? Coffeescript code is more compact...

Comment: I love Spine.  Use it with RequireJS for pure awesomeness.  Don't let the fact that it's CoffeeScript scare you off either, it works fine with normal JS, too...

Comment: Browser support is IE >= 9 so check that matches the profile of your visitors.

Answer (score 20):

AngularJS works well together with jQuery and will help you a lot with MVC structure and strict separation of concerns.

Full testing environment and Dependency Injection included...

Check it out at http://angularjs.org

Comment: Angularjs is THE best so far in late 2013.... I think....

Comment: angular is not a micro framework :/

Comment: Agree, Angular is not a micro-framework.

Comment: yes, also the learning curve is non-proportional it's benefits comparing to other frameworks.

Comment: angular is the very opposite of a micro framework. it's a beast.

Answer (score 14):

Indeed there is: [http://www.javascriptmvc.com/](http://javascriptmvc.com/)

I think you will find this sufficient!

Comment: That site has a blink tag.  o_0

Comment: that site doesn't load for me at all

Comment: Try again, should work again.

Answer (score 14):

I think this one looks like something you should check out: http://knockoutjs.com/

(As a silverlight / wpf programmer this was the library that made me finally start learning javascript. It is based on the Model-View-View-Model (MVVM) pattern, as for me right now seems like a good choise!)

Comment: As a silverlight / wpf programmer I evaluated knockout, backbone, and a couple others. At the end of the day I switched to Angular. It has bindings and MUCH more.

Answer (score 8):

There is the popular [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)

Answer (score 8):

[Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/)

These are the three features that make Ember a joy to use:

1. Bindings
2. Computed properties
3. Auto-updating templates

#### Bindings

Use bindings to keep properties between two different objects in sync. You just declare a binding once, and Ember will make sure changes get propagated in either direction.

Here's how you create a binding between two objects:

```
MyApp.president = Ember.Object.create({
  name: "Barack Obama"
});

MyApp.country = Ember.Object.create({
  // Ending a property with 'Binding' tells Ember to
  // create a binding to the presidentName property.
  presidentNameBinding: 'MyApp.president.name'
});

MyApp.country.get('presidentName');
// "Barack Obama"
```

Bindings allow you to architect your application using the MVC (Model-View-Controller) pattern, then rest easy knowing that data will always flow correctly from layer to layer.

#### Computed Properties

Computed properties allow you to treat a function like a property.
Computed properties are useful because they can work with bindings, just like any other property.

#### Auto-updating Templates

Ember uses Handlebars, a semantic templating library. To take data from your JavaScript application and put it into the DOM, create a  tag and put it into your HTML, wherever you'd like the value to appear:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  The President of the United States is {{MyApp.president.fullName}}.
</script>
```

Comment: is ember advantageous to use over backbone in any way.... if the specifications are not so clear at the initial stages..

Comment: I do like emberJS, but it is not **"micro"** it's **HUGE** because its a flat out framework

Comment: Using Ember and microframework in the same sentence shouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 8):

[Stapes.js](http://hay.github.com/stapes/)

Full disclosure: i'm the author of this library :)

If you're looking for something really tiny (1.5kb minified / gzipped) have a look, and tell me if you like it.

Comment: Looks great at first sight! I like your focus on prototypal inheritance (no simulated classes, and no confusing `new` operator). What seems unnecessary is yet another `each` and `map`. I already have them in [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 7):

If your requirements are *really* simple, you could write your own simple MVC like [Alex Netkachov](http://www.alexatnet.com/node/8) did.

His examples are built on dojo (Note: they don't work for me on his page because of a missing dojo.js file), but you could follow the pattern in plain Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably overkill for what you need, but **[SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/)** is an MVC framework, and it doesn't look any more heavyweight than **[JavaScriptMVC](http://www.javascriptmvc.com/)** or TrimPath's **[Junction](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/TrimJunction)**.

Unfortunately, none of these seem to be built on the principle of [progressive enhancement](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/#progressive-enhancement).

Comment: JavaScriptMVC's core MVC components are about 1k larger than Backbone's gzipped (while have a number more features).  And JMVC is fully able to build progressively enhanced apps.  You'd just throw away the Model layer.

Answer (score 3):

The popular ActionScript MVC framework [PureMVC](http://trac.puremvc.org/PureMVC_JS/) was recently ported to JavaScript. I haven't had a chance to try it out yet, but I am confident it's good.

Comment: I like it for flex. Simple and powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Please also checkout [jquery-claypool](https://github.com/thatcher/jquery-claypool).

jquery-claypool is a small, fast, railable mvc framework built on jquery, based on my experience with django, rails, spring etc.  Its very light weight and runs on both on the client and in server environments.

it provides a routing framework for clean mvc, category logging, filters (aop), lazy creation of controllers, inversion of control, convention-over-configuration and not much more by design.

it doesn't do anything jquery already does, feels like jquery, and works like a good framework should: simply.

[jquery-claypool](http://www.claypooljs.com)

Hope you check it out.

Comment: How do you see Claypool in relation to Backbone?

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE 2016: Sammy.js seems to be abandoned.

### Have a look at [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org)

Text from the site:

*A small webframework with class.*

- **SMALL** Sammy's core is only 16K compressed and 5.2K compressed and gzipped
- **MODULAR** Sammy is built on a system of plugins and adapters . Only include the code you need. It's also easy to extract your own code into reusable plugins.
- **CLEAN** The entire API was designed to be easy to understand and read. Sammy tries to encourage good encapsulation and application design.
- **FUN** What's the real point of development if its not enjoyable. Sammy tries to follow the MATZ approach. It is optimized for developer happiness.

Comment: Could you expand, please, on what is MATZ?

Comment: Yukihiro “Matz” Matsumoto, the creator of ruby has often said that he is “trying to make Ruby natural, not simple,” in a way that mirrors life. So software should feel natural to the user. This is meant by MATZ approach.

Answer (score 2):

Jamal is the lightweightest I've seen.  It's also based on jQuery (bonus).  Have not used.

http://jamal-mvc.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep things under control and quite simple, you may don't need a framework, but just implement your own mvc pattern.
Just check this article: [Model-View-Controller (MVC) with JavaScript](http://www.alexatnet.com/content/model-view-controller-mvc-javascript) by Alex Netkachov on 2006.

Answer (score 2):

Try [kitty](https://github.com/msn0/jsKitty-MVC). It is only 1.4KB and its only dependency is EJS.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of all open-source JavaScript Frameworks known to mankind.

http://getopensource.info/explore/javascript/framework/

Or only MVC frameworks

http://getopensource.info/explore/javascript/mvc/

Disclosure: I'm the developer of this website.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this a *micro*-framework, but it sure looks interesting: [Cappuccino Web Framework](http://cappuccino.org/)

Answer (score 1):

CorMVC, easy to understand and to start with, jquery based and does not depend on any server technology

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a very simple Javascript MVC framework called [MCV](http://projects.andreaferretti.it/mcv). It does not do exactly what you ask for, but it is easily extensible with helpers. Anyway, it is definitely micro (1,9kb packed).

It works more or less like Jamal, but I decided to roll my own for two reasons:

- remove the jQuery dependency (although I use it together with jQuery most of the time)
- making it extensible with helpers. These are analog to CakePHP behaviors, components and helpers.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make the list a little more complete:
[ActiveJS](http://activejs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted the AngularJS (full disclosure, I'm involved in a limited way with the angular dev effort) and am very excited about it. I did a side-by-side comparison taking one feature for an internal project (sorry don't have signoff to share it) and implementing it in both AngularJS and Backbone. It was a great exercise and in the end, I'm very much leaning towards Angular. The core developers are great about answering questions and they've done a really nice job with builtin databinding, unit/e2e testing and documentation. Its still in beta with 1.0 coming out in near future. The beta is very stable.

There is a bit of a paradigm shift, and they use a fairly different approach than most. Integrating your favorite jquery plugins takes a bit of effort but is doable and has been done (angular-contrib on github).

I will say (and this is a problem for most js-centric frameworks), make sure to investigate how to make your content SEO-friendly (if its important to you). Since joining the angular community in June, I've noticed the interest is growing and a number of people are making posts saying that they've looked at Backbone and others but really like what they are seeing in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

There was a key-value binding JavaScript framework called "Coherent", which was inspired by Apple's Cocoa Bindings. The framework has been bought by Apple, but there is still an old copy at http://github.com/trek/coherentjs/tree/master.

Answer (score 0):

Maverick is a small JavaScript MVC framework — http://maverick.round.ee

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to pipe up here too -  [AFrameJS](http://www.aframejs.com) works with jQuery, MooTools and Prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jQuery based javascript MVC framework](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-neat-mvc/jQuery-neat-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

Another one: [MooTools-MVC](https://github.com/fate/Mootools-MVC)

Answer (score 0):

One more, lightweight and tiny: http://jqnano.oleksiy.pro/

Answer (score 0):

**[Can.js](http://canjs.us/)** has everything you need and weighs in at just 8 KB. It's taken the best bits from JavaScriptMVC and distilled it into one small, yet kickass framework with observers, widgets, binding, the works. It is compatible with major frameworks ([jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), [Dojo Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit), [MooTools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MooTools), etc.). Documentation is excellent and authors are responsive. It is definitely worth a look.