# Using MVC to implement a framework in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm doing .NET MVC a lot so I think I understand the MVC design pattern. I'm analyzing my projects according to the Domain Driven Design (Eric Evans) methodology. Anyways..

But in JavaScript it's hard for me to think "MVC" when I'm creating libraries.

Do you have a small example or any experience to share with me on how a small JavaScript could use the MVC design pattern?

I'm quite comfortable with JavaScript.

Thanks!

Comment: Solution looking for a problem?

Comment: lol I must agree. But the problems will come soon enough ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google [lists](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHMB_enUS329US329&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mvc+javascript) numerous examples.

1. Official Website of [Javascript MVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/)

   - [Demo Video](http://cdn.javascriptmvc.com/videos/2_0/2_0_demo.htm)
2. *A List Apart* - [Jonathan Snook on Javascript MVC](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/javascript-mvc/)
3. *CodeCube.net* - [MVC Pattern with Javascript](http://codecube.net/2009/06/mvc-pattern-with-javascript/)
4. *StackOverflow* - [Is there a Javascript MVC (micro-)framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386885/is-there-a-javascript-mvc-micro-framework)

Comment: Thanks, usually I do that but a quick side to side talk is helpful. I'll do my homework though. I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, check out [javascriptmvc](http://javascriptmvc.com).  It's like rails for JavaScript.  Makes very strong use of event delegation.