# jQuery, Web Application Framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, javascript-framework

For the longest time I've used jQuery to hack together web sites. Now I'm interested in making a web application (one page load for the entire site to function, like Gmail).

Are there any jQuery Frameworks or practices that I can leverage to build my application so I don't have to recreate the wheel, or hack something together as I go?

Thanks

Comment: Since jQuery is a JavaScript library, you can leverage on the frameworks that already exist for JavaScript. I.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386885/is-there-a-javascript-mvc-micro-framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the (not so) many options is [JavascriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/), which is pretty cool and I've used it for one midium-size project.

It's website is pretty discouraging, but give it a chance and watch [the video](http://javascriptmvc.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/2_0/2_0_demo.htm). One possitive aspect is that it's creator always answers really fast in JMVC's google group.

But, actually, if I had to remake the project I mentioned, I would not use it, as jQuery provides (almost) all JMVC's functionality, you just have to get used to it. For an example in how to handle big apps with jQuery, I would recommend you to [watch this video](http://vimeo.com/9998565) between others of [Alex Sexton](http://alexsexton.com/) and other members of the [yayQuery podcast](http://yayquery.com/).

Comment: Great answer! I concur! I also have an article on the subject on scriptjunkie - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff728622.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I honestly don't know how someone could say jQuery provides almost all of JMVC's functionality.  Yes, you can do a lot of similar things with jQuery, but you would have to write it an maintain it yourself.

Here's a quick list of what JavaScriptMVC provides that jQuery does not: (read more of them at http://jupiterjs.com/news/javascriptmvc-features)

- Dependency Management
- Building / Compression
- Logging
- Organized Folder Structures
- Package Management
- Code Cleaning
- Functional Testing
- Client Side Templates
- A bunch of delegatable special events (drag-drop, hover, resize, etc)
- A bunch of dom utilities
- Language Extensions
- An awesome widget factory
- Documentation

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into Sammy.js? It's an mvc framework built on JQuery and is very beginner friendly. http://code.quirkey.com/sammy/