# Ruby on Rails for Javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, frameworks

I have some experience in Ruby on Rails and I want to keep the MVC way to go in my client side Javascript project.

There is any Rails-like framework for Javascript? It should have the following features:

- MVC
- Easy integration with REST web services
- Javascript-driven templating system
- Models and validations
- Testing framework

A solid documentation is a must!

Answer (score 2):

I discovered [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) today. It's worth a look. It appears to be a lightweight abstract MVC system and uses [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

As for client side testing this isn't included. There are many standalone unit testing libraries out there.

Just add in any client side testing library you want. With these 4 you really shouldn't need anything else.

There are more heavyweight alternatives like [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) or [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/)#

Also see a large thread here on the topic by people in the [know](http://ryth.posterous.com/sproutcore-vs-jquery-backbonejs)

I think [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is worthy a mention aswell in case you want to delegate some of your framework to the server but keep it in javascript. You'll have to look into some of the big libraries running on node though.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://emberjs.com/. It's very ambitious Javascript framework with cool things like UI Bindings and Auto-updating templates. It plays well with jQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript MVC is pretty full-featured and has a lot of good testing tools included: http://javascriptmvc.com/

Check out this answer for more info:
[Is there a JavaScript MVC (micro-)framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386885/is-there-a-javascript-mvc-micro-framework)