# Asp.Net MVC: Generate dynamic view based on JSON OR C# class object data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

As I am working on `Asp.Net MVC 3`, I want to `create an UI based on JSON object`.

E.g. Consider that I have a `complex JSON object` which contains `string, array, boolean properties with data`.

Now, I want to `create an UI which should render dynamic textbox based on JSON object`.

For example, `if my JSON object have array inside it`, then it should generate `dynamic gridview kind of UI which should contains textbox` inside it.

In short, I want to `create a dynamic view based on JSON object`.

Could anybody please suggest me how could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

(Could anybody suggest on this?)

Comment: Have you tried something? There is some moments, which you are not described. From where you get JSON? AJAX?

Comment: See what I will do it.. I will have a JSON string response by calling web service and then I will deserialize in my C# poco class, and I want to create dynamic UI from this my C# poco class object...

Comment: I would go for some EditorTemplates for a fully fledged C# Model. Once you go with Js/JSON you're doomed to client side programming, and actually loose the powe of Razor views.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question about javascript UI than c#.  It sounds like your controller methods are all set in terms of returning the appropriate JSON result.

There are a number of javascript mvc frameworks that are meant to be used for complex client applications.  [javascript MVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/) and [sproutcore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) are the 2 i'm most familiar with but [there are others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386885/is-there-a-javascript-mvc-micro-framework)

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) from twitter is a rich stylesheet and javascript solution that makes it easy to build relatively nice UIs.

[YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) from yahoo is the grandfather of javascript frameworks, but it has a lot of widgets as does [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: sure, but these do all just care about structuring your client-side JavaScript web application but do not provide facilities for dynamically creating views out of JSON objects.