# Looking for JS MVC framework with templating

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, templating

I've been looking at a few client side JS frameworks like SproutCore and JavaScriptMVC, but was wondering if anyone could recommend a JS framework or template engine that has template inheritance support?

For example, if I have a base template, I want to be able to extend templates using the base template, similar to what [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) template engine does with the `{% extend '...' %}` tag

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you what around tempting, but ExtJS 4.0 has an MVC implementation and the XTemplate class for visual/html templating, it also has the ability to extend all it's components and classes, in fact, that's how views are normally defined (by extending their existing components).

Have a look here: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs

Comment: I think you'll find that while ExtJS is based on the principle of extensible classes/components, the templates themselves arent extensible other than at a class level (where the old template is copied into the new type definition).

Comment: Yeah I was a bit unsure what his requirement was on the topic of templates. 
The templates in ExtJS are really powerful but as you say I don't think they can be extended as such. If Josef could give us some more info though there may be a sensible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this post handy for a list of MVC frameworks.

[Is there a JavaScript MVC (micro-)framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386885/is-there-a-javascript-mvc-micro-framework)

With some additional templating support on: [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/), [_.template](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template), [Haml-js](https://github.com/creationix/haml-js), [eco](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco)

As far as I'm aware none of the options out there support this kind of extensible templates, I think its an awesome idea though.

Answer (score 0):

[Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) allows you to plug in your own templating engine.  By default it uses jquery templates, but if you find one that meets your requirements you can swap it in(e.g. [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [moustache](http://mustache.github.com/)).  I have been using backbone for a while and I am quite happy with it as a client-side "pseudo-MVC" framework.